# how to make dropdown work using up and down arrow keys in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i am trying to make a custom dropdown using react where it should work with keyboard up and down keys also

this is what i tried so far

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import "./dropdown.scss";

const Dropdown = ({ selected, setSelected }) => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const options = ["Option1", "Option2", "Option3", "Option4"];
  const [cursor, setCurser] = useState(0);

  //   const label = ["frontend", "backend"];

  let menuRef = useRef();
  // let menuRef1 = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    let handler = (e) => {
      if (!menuRef.current.contains(e.target)) {
        setOpen(false);
      }
    };
    document.addEventListener("mousedown", handler);
    return () => {
      document.removeEventListener("mousedown", handler);
    };
  });

 

  const handleKeyDown = (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 38 && cursor > 0) {
      setCurser({
        ...cursor,
        cursor: cursor + 1,
      });
      console.log(cursor);
    } else if (e.keyCode === 40 && cursor < options.length - 1) {
      setCurser({
        ...cursor,
        cursor: cursor - 1,
      });
    }
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div className="dropdown">
        <div
          ref={menuRef}
          onKeyPress={handleKeyDown}
          className={
            open ? "dropdown-wrapper--up dropdown-wrapper " : "dropdown-wrapper"
          }
        >
          <div className="dropdown-container">
            <div
              className={"dropdown-header"}
              onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
              // ref={menuRef1}
            >
              {!open ? (
                <div className={selected ? "title-active " : "dropdown-title"}>
                  {selected ? selected : "dropdown-select"}
                </div>
              ) : (
                <div className={selected ? "active-color " : "dropdown-title"}>
                  {selected ? selected : "dropdown-select"}
                </div>
              )}
              <i
                className={open ? "fas fa-chevron-up" : "fas fa-chevron-down"}
              ></i>
            </div>
            {open ? (
              <div
                className={selected ? "active-label active-label--up" : "label"}
              >
                {open ? "Hint Text" : "Title"}{" "}
              </div>
            ) : (
              <div className={selected ? "active-label " : "label "}>
                {open ? "Hint Text" : "Title"}{" "}
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
          {open && (
            <ul className="list">
              {options.map((option, i) => (
                <li
                  onClick={() => {
                    setSelected(option);
                    setOpen(false);
                  }}
                  className="list-item"
                  tabIndex="0"
                >
                  {option}
                </li>
              ))}
            </ul>
          )}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dropdown;
```

here is the output

[image]

i want to move between options using up and down arrow key... tried many solutions but not working

i am using array as option list and mapping through it and displaying in dropdown.
everything is working fine but just dont know how to map keyboard keys to option list

Answer (score 4):

You can create an Array of refs for each option

```
const optionRefs = useRef(options.map(() => createRef()));
```

then use the these refs

```js
options.map((option, index) => (<li ... ref={optionRefs.current[index]} >...</li>)
```

and then change the focus to the ref when you navigate...
like focussing the first on down arrow:

```
optionRefs.current[0].current?.focus();
```